# Error:not well-formed (invalid-token)

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio

I was creating a simple layout but when I build the application. I got this error-not well-formed invalid token in my XML file.

[image: Screenshot]

I am facing a different problem with my Android Studio, should I reinstall my studio.
I was trying to create Udacity project for CourtCounter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TeamViewer">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:text="Team A"
           />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:text="Total Score:"
           />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:text="zests"
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Team B"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Total Score:"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="bcx"
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages.  Copy/paste the relevant portions into your question and format as code (use the `{}` button in the editor toolbar)

Comment: "not well-formed" means your XML file has a structural error. The message says it's at line 33.  If you want more help you will need to provide the XML file.

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting to close the tag in the following line:

```
       ...

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:text="zests"
 </LinearLayout>
```

add `/>` so it will become:

```
       ...

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:text="zests"
       />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Please check your another line.

**P.S** You can see the missing line in your question (look at the black colored line).